# Multiply table using while loop C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, multiplication

I am trying to create a Multiply table using a while loop but I don't understand why While(x<=sk1) loop is executing I <=sk1 loop only once.

```
int x = 1;

Console.Write("Enter number under 20: ");
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
int sk1 = int.Parse(input1);

while (sk1 > 20)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number once again: ");
    input1 = Console.ReadLine();
    sk1 = int.Parse(input1);
}

while (x <= sk1)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= sk1)
    {
        Console.Write($" {i*x} ");
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Did you not debug it and see for yourself?

Comment: when you enter the "while (x <= sk1)" you need to set "i = 1" I think

Comment: Have you run the code step by step through the debugger? Note that you're not resetting `i` before the nested `while` loop, so after the first iteration of the outer loop, the condition will stay false.

Comment: for Input, you should use a do...while loop. They run at least once, and can be repeated until the user starts making sense. Also use TryParse instead of Parse would help somewhat with robustness. And make the whole thing more readable. | I am also unsure why you use a while loop, for what is obviously for loop work?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you very much the tip, now all is clear for me.

Comment: why not nested `for` instead of nested `while`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko its task from my programming course , i had to do it using a While loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's *simplify* the problem:

1. Split the task into: user input and table generation
2. Choose readable names (what does `sk1` mean?)

Code:

```
private static int ReadPositiveInteger(int maxValue) {
  while (true) {
    Console.Write($"Enter positive number under {maxValue}: "); 

    if (!int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
      Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a integer value");
    else if (result <= 0)
      Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a positive integer value");
    else if (result > maxValue) 
      Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, the value must be not greater than {maxValue}");
    else
      return result; 
    }
  }
```

Having a `size` let's build the tables:

```
private static void PrintMultiplyTable(int size) {
  int row = 1; 

  while (row <= size) {
    int column = 1;

    while (column <= size) {
      Console.WriteLine($" {row * column,3}"); // ,3 - formatting

      column += 1; 
    }

    row += 1;    
  } 
}
```

Now, in order draw the table you can put (sonewhere in `Main` method)

```
PrintMultiplyTable(ReadPositiveInteger(20));
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the loop.

```
int x = 1;

while (x <= sk1)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= sk1)
    {
        //Do some stuff here
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    x++;
}
```

In your case it looped one time because you entered 1 as a user input. `sk1 = 1`

- Put a breakpoint on your code and you will see that the second time
  `i == 2`. So, `i` is no longer smaller or equal to `sk1`. (2 is not smaller than or equal to 1)
- Now `x == 2` and `x` is no longer smaller or equal to `sk1`. (2 is not smaller than or equal to 1)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution in the end, works properly.

```
int x = 1;        
Console.Write("Enter number under 20: ");
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
int num1 = int.Parse(input1);

while (num1 > 20)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number once again: ");
    input1 = Console.ReadLine();
    num1 = int.Parse(input1);
}

while (x <= num1)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= num1)
    {
        Console.Write($" {i*x} ");
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    x++;
}
```